# Prove that cardinality of $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ are same.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following sets:

> > $A=$ set of sequence of real nos.

> > $B=$ set of sequence of positive real nos

> > $C=$ $\mathbb R$

> > $D= C[0,1]$

then prove that cardinality of $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ are same. I think there we can construct a map from $\Bbb R$ to $C[0,1]$ by associating each point of $\Bbb R$ to its constant function. Then this is bijective map so $C$ ,$D$ have same cardinality.

Comment: is indicator function in $C[0,1]$

Comment: upps......sorry....no....

Comment: Can we take the constant map?

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in[0,1]$ define $f_n(x)$ as the number formed by first writing the decimal expansion of $x=0.x_1x_2...$ (note that $1=0.999...$) and then counting through the digits but resetting the counter whenever we reach a new "maximal count" like this
$$
\begin{array}{c}
digits:&x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&x_6&x_7&x_8&x_9&x_{10}&x_{11}&x_{12}&x_{13}&x_{14}&x_{15}&...\\
counter:&1&1&2&1&2&3&1&2&3&4&1&2&3&4&5&...
\end{array}
$$
and finally forming the number $f_n(x)\in[0,1]$ that has all the digits of $x$ for which the counter was $n$. This maps each $x\in[0,1]$ to an infinite sequences $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $[0,1]$. Note that $g(x)=\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is surjective since from $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ we can easily construct $x\in[0,1]$ mapping to it. It is now easy to see, that
$$
h(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}-1&x\in(0,1]\\
&\\
0&x=0
\end{cases}
$$ 
satisfies $h([0,1])=\mathbb R^+$. So $x\longmapsto\{h(f_n(x))\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defines a surjection from $D$ to $B$.

---

With a little more work, it should be easy to construct functions mapping $[0,1]$ to $[-1,1]$ and then to $\mathbb R$, the first being a linear map, the second exploiting the ideas from $h$ above, and then combining those with $f_n(x)$ we quickly have a surjection from $D$ to $A$.

---

To sum up, I just proved that $|D|\geq|B|$ and outlined that $|D|\geq|A|$. If you can show $|B|\geq|D|$ and $|A|\geq|C|\geq|D|$ you can conclude $|A|=|B|=|C|=|D|$ by combining results.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I misread set $D$ as the interval $[0,1]$ and not $C([0,1])$. But my argument above still shows that $|C|\geq|[0,1]|\geq|A|,|B|$ which is part of what we need.

Answer (score 0):

A has cardinality $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}=c$

Check that B also has same cardinality as A and $\mathbb R$ has cardinality as $c$

Comment: Not getting. Can you explain more?

Comment: what are you not getting?

Comment: A B are same? how?

Comment: what is cardinality of $\mathbb R^+$